# Pandas: Delete rows where no value is populated in any of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below dataframe:

```
Name Age Tag1 Tag2 Tag3 Tag4 Tag5
A    10   1    2    3    55   6
B    23   4    0    5    0    9
C    19   2    0    0    0    0
D    30   0    0    0    0    0
E    44   0    0    0    4    0
```

From the above dataframe i want to remove those rows which do not have any entries in columns Tag1 till Tag5. In this example, it would be row D

Is there a clean way to do this on a very huge dataframe?

I have tried this but i don't this this is a right approach as i have to use OR condition here. If value is present in any of the columns, it should not delete that row.

```
result_fin[result_fin['Tag1', 'Tag2', 'Tag3', 'Tag4', 'Tag5'] > 0]
```

Comment: `df[~df.filter(like="Tag").eq(0).all(1)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`df.any(1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html)

```
>>> df[(df[df.columns[2:]]).any(1)]
  Name  Age  Tag1  Tag2  Tag3  Tag4  Tag5
0    A   10     1     2     3    55     6
1    B   23     4     0     5     0     9
2    C   19     2     0     0     0     0
4    E   44     0     0     0     4     0
```

Or, vice versa with [`df.all(1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html#pandas.DataFrame.all)

```
>>> df[~(df[df.columns[2:]]==0).all(1)]
  Name  Age  Tag1  Tag2  Tag3  Tag4  Tag5
0    A   10     1     2     3    55     6
1    B   23     4     0     5     0     9
2    C   19     2     0     0     0     0
4    E   44     0     0     0     4     0
```

`(1)` suggests you want to look along the `axis 1`

Instead of `df.columns[2:]` you could also specify the column names `['Tag1', 'Tag2', 'Tag3', 'Tag4', 'Tag5']`.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace 0's with `np.nan` and use `dropna` to drop corresponding rows

```
df = df.replace({0:np.nan}).dropna(subset=["tag1","tag2","tag3","tag4","tag5"], 
                                   how="all").fillna(0)
```